# How to display the items hidden using display="none" which are stored in an array without losing it's old properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

### JavaScript

```
 function hideSideMenu() {
            if(document.getElementById("arrow-left").className === "arrow-left fa fa-arrow-left") {
            var k = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title');
            for (var i = 0;i < k.length ; i++) {
                /*k[i].style.display = 'none' ;*/
                     /*k[i].style.removeProperty('display') ;*/
            }
            var m =document.getElementsByClassName('spinner-ico');
            for (var j = 0;j < m.length; j++) {
                m[j].style.display = '' ;
            }
            document.getElementById('navbar').className="navbar-after-click";

            document.getElementById('top-container').className="top-container-after-click";
            document.getElementById('innerContnt').className="inner-content-after-click";
            document.getElementById('footer').className="footer-after-click";
            document.getElementById('logo').className="logo-after-click";
            document.getElementById("arrow-left").className="arrow-left-after-click fa fa-bars";
        }
         else{
            //echo("i'm working");
            var k = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-title');
            for (var i = 0;i < k.length ; i++) {
                k[i].style.display = 'block' ;
            }
              var m =document.getElementsByClassName('spinner-ico');
            for (var j = 0;j < m.length; j++) {
                m[j].style.display = 'block' ;
            }
            document.getElementById('innerContnt').className="inner-content"; 
            document.getElementById("arrow-left").className="arrow-left fa fa-arrow-left";
             document.getElementById('footer').className="footer";
             document.getElementById('top-container').className="top-container";
             document.getElementById('logo').className="logo";
        }


    }
```

### HMTL

```
     <ul id="leftMenu" class="clearfix">
                   <li class="topmenu ltopmenu-display-event"><a href="http://qmsadm.local/dashboard"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-dashboard                                                          
 "></span><span id="menu-title"
 class="menu-title">Dashboard</span></a></li><li class="topmenu
 ltopmenu-display-event"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="ico
 fa fa-fw fa-globe                                                     
 "></span><span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">Admin</span><span
 class="fa  fa-chevron-right spinner-ico"></span></a><ul><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/admin/users"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-users                                                              
 "></span>Users</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/admin/roles"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-user-md                                                            
 "></span>Roles</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/admin/menu"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-navicon                                                            
 "></span>Manage Menu</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/admin/clients"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-pagelines                                                          
 "></span>Clients</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/admin/templates"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-glass                                                              
 "></span>Templates</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/admin/devreqs"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-cloud-upload                                                       
 "></span>Device Requests</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/admin/devices"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-laptop                                                             
 "></span>Devices</a></li></ul></li><li class="topmenu
 ltopmenu-display-event"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="ico
 fa fa-fw fa-puzzle-piece                                              
 "></span><span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">App</span><span
 class="fa  fa-chevron-right spinner-ico"></span></a><ul><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/app/counters"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-ticket                                                             
 "></span>Counters</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/app/displays"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-desktop                                                            
 "></span>Displays</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/app/kiosks"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-hand-o-up                                                          
 "></span>Kiosks</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/app/ads"><span class="ico fa fa-fw fa-film  
 "></span>Ads</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/app/category"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-star                                                               
 "></span>Category</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/app/subcategory"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-star-half                                                          
 "></span>Sub Category</a></li></ul></li><li class="topmenu
 ltopmenu-display-event"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="ico
 fa fa-fw fa-pie-chart                                                 
 "></span><span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">Reports</span><span
 class="fa  fa-chevron-right spinner-ico"></span></a><ul><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/reports/token/detail"><span class="ico fa
 fa-fw fa-th-large                                                     
 "></span>Token Detail</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/reports/token/summary"><span class="ico fa
 fa-fw fa-envelope-o                                                   
 "></span>Token Summary</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/reports/counter/detail"><span class="ico fa
 fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o                                              
 "></span>Counter Detail</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/reports/counter/summary"><span class="ico fa
 fa-fw fa-briefcase                                                    
 "></span>Counter Summary</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/reports/regusers"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-dedent                                                             
 "></span>Registered Users</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/reports/admin/activities"><span class="ico
 fa fa-fw fa-clipboard                                                 
 "></span>Admin Activities</a></li></ul></li><li class="topmenu
 ltopmenu-display-event"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="ico
 fa fa-fw fa-gears                                                     
 "></span><span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">Settings</span><span
 class="fa  fa-chevron-right spinner-ico"></span></a><ul><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/settings/personal"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-columns                                                            
 "></span>Personal</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/settings/language"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-bold                                                               
 "></span>Language</a></li><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/settings/client"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-male                                                               
 "></span>Client</a></li></ul></li><li class="topmenu
 ltopmenu-display-event"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="ico
 fa fa-fw fa-anchor                                                    
 "></span><span id="menu-title" class="menu-title">Super</span><span
 class="fa  fa-chevron-right spinner-ico"></span></a><ul><li><a
 href="http://qmsadm.local/super/activities"><span class="ico fa fa-fw
 fa-pencil                                                             
 "></span>Activities</a></li></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li><ul></ul></li>

                 </ul>
               </li>
                       </ul>
```

In the above code i'm tried to hide the menu items `onclick`. i'm tried the following things.

1. `k[i].style.display = 'none';`
2. `k[i].style.display = "";`
3. `k[i].style.removeProperty('display') ;`

In the above three options only first one(`display='none'`) works for me.but the problem is when display the code after hide using `display="none"` some styles are changed (padding,margin,etc..).How i can fix this?

Comment: try to use jquery, because it has more possabilitys . nicer handlers. and it is smoother from the Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure If I got you, there's a bunch of codes with no live demo, but if you say that you get some props chanched when you display second time, try to add  the following to your code to make sure:

`if(display ! == none) {//you can hide now}`

This will make the code run only when the items are visible

Comment: i not added live demo because which contain php part also, i don't see a part to add php code in snippet.i don't understand what you mean,can you explain some thing?

Comment: i added the html code just to understand what the class name indicates

Comment: You said that the first option works only first time, after that you make more changes than needed. Try to do the following, make the changes only if needed. Think your code like a box. If the box is closed, open it, but if the box is already open, don't do the same thing again. An `if()` loop will prevent your code for executing second time if the cahnges are made

Comment: i'm edited,expecting you understand the real problem